# block ip with iptables ubuntu server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, iptables, ip

I am trying to block one IP with iptables in my Ubuntu server 12.04.

The foreign IP is 117.16.18.95.dyna. You can take a look at the next image:

[image]

I have added this ip to iptables with the next command:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 117.16.18.95 -p tcp -j DROP
sudo service iptables-persistent save
sudo service iptables-persistent restart
```

However, when i run again the command `netstat -tap`, this IP is not blocked.

How can I remove/block/delete this IP from my Ubuntu server?

Comment: add a -n to the netstat command and confirm the IP address is correct.

Comment: Please use [Markdown](http://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts to improve their readability. Also use cut-and-paste for posting console output and format it as "`code`" rather than posting screenshots. That improves readability, attracts better answers  and allows indexing by search engines, which may help people with similar questions.

Comment: If you want the `-p` option to `netstat` to actually work, you must run it with `sudo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IP adresses contains only digits. So '117.16.18.95.dyna' is definitely not IP, it is FQDN. I suspect that real ip is reversed. So, try to block 95.18.16.117 
Or just to ensure try netstat with '-n' arg, it will prevent IPs from resolving to FQDNs

Answer (score 3):

iptables `-A` will append the rule to the end of your rule set. If there is any rule before that IP allowing these connections somehow, the rule will never be hit, since the order of processing in iptable rules are up to down. Furthermore. There may also be rules like stateful iptable rules (eg `RELATED,ESTABLISHED`) which will allow connections if the session was initiated by your host.

Check with `iptables -L -v -n` and read  the output. There are counters there which can tell if your rule has ever been in effect.

Also, you can append your rule to the top of the INPUT chain instead of to the bottom by replacing the `-A` (append) with `-I` (insert).

Comment: That's a good answer. When you say counter, you mean `pkts` ?

Comment: indeed yes pkts!